# Other Fragments are not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been searching for showing `fragments` but the problem still exists and I can't get it to work.

my problem is when ever I add `repeat_entry` to menu for showing another fragment, that fragment is not showing but when I click on `action_settings` the fragment for that one is showing.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,android.R.animator.fade_out);

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            selectTabToShow(String.valueOf(R.id.action_search));
            CategorySettings fragemnt = (CategorySettings) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.categorySettings);
            fragemnt.refresCategoryList();
            Fragment fragment = new CategorySettings();
            ft.add(R.id.category_cont,fragment,"asdf");
            ft.commit();
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.repeat_entry){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ssdf sdf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Fragment fragment = new RepeatEntry();
            ft.add(R.id.category_cont,fragment,"repeat tag");
            ft.commit();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ssdf sdf",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

As of now this is my RepeatEntry fragments

```
public class RepeatEntry extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.repeat_entry,container,false);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Please help me guys I'm new to this.

Comment: please post the code for RepeatEntry(); fragment.

Comment: @jameshwart, try to use getChildFragmentManager() intead of getFragmentManager()

Comment: @Anand Raj getChildFragmentManager() sir , i get an error of cannot resolve method sir

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
ft.replace(R.id.category_cont,fragment,"repeat tag");
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but it did not work sir :(